# How to change multiple cell values in Google Sheets via Apps Script?

Tags: javascript, arrays, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I want to write a script to format a production schedule for printing. I want to enter single letters, then run the script to change those single letters into words and format the cells with borders, etc.

The following if/ else if/ else operation does what I want for a single cell:

```
    var TESTalpha = printCHSheet.getRange(4, 5, 1, 1);
    var TESTalphaData = TESTalpha.getValue();

    if (TESTalphaData == 'f') {
    TESTalpha.clear();
    TESTalpha.setValue('FAB').setBorder(true, true, true, true, true, true);
    } else if (TESTalphaData == 'p') {
    TESTalpha.clear();
    TESTalpha.setValue('PAINT').setBorder(true, true, true, true, true, true);
    } else if (TESTalphaData == 'c') {
    TESTalpha.clear();
    TESTalpha.setValue('FINISH').setBorder(true, true, true, true, true, true);
    } else {
    TESTalpha.setValue(null);
    }
```

Eventually I want to apply this to a range of cells in rows and columns, but first I am trying to evaluate five cells on a single row.

The following loop runs, but replaces every cell with the last value it finds (FYI...the five cells E4:I4 are populated with f/ f/ p/ c/ c):

```
    var TESTalpha = printCHSheet.getRange(4, 5, 1, 5);
    var TESTlength = TESTalpha.getLastColumn();
    var TESTalphaData = TESTalpha.getValues();

    for (var i=0; i < TESTlength+1; i++) {
    if (TESTalphaData[0][i] == "f") {
    TESTalpha.clear();
    TESTalpha.setValue("FAB");
    } else if (TESTalphaData[0][i] == "p") {
    TESTalpha.clear();
    TESTalpha.setValue("PAINT");
    } else if (TESTalphaData[0][i] == "c") {
    TESTalpha.clear();
    TESTalpha.setValue("FINISH");
    }
    }
```

The result I get here is that all cells in range E4:I4 are set to FAB; then all set to PAINT; then all set to FINISH. What I want to have, rather, is FAB/ FAB/ PAINT/ FINISH/ FINISH. I know the above script is replacing all the cells because I'm programming it to, but my various modifications have failed, so I post it here as possibly heading in the right direction.

Another idea I had is to run a loop to splice the array, then clear the range and set (or push) the new array modified by the loop:

```
    var TESTalpha = spreadsheet.getRange("E4:I4");
    var TESTlength = TESTalpha.getLastColumn();

    for (var i=0; i < TESTlength+1; i++) {

    var TESTalphaData = TESTalpha.getValues();

    if (TESTalphaData[0][i] == "f") {
    TESTalphaData.splice([i], 1, "FAB");
    } else if (TESTalphaData[0][i] == "p") {
    TESTalphaData.splice([i], 1, "PAINT");
    } else if (TESTalphaData[0][i] == "c") {
    TESTalphaData.splice([i], 1, "FINISH");
    } 

    spreadsheet.getRange("E4:I4").clear();
    spreadsheet.getRange("E4:I4").setValues(TESTalphaData);

    }
```

The problem with the above is (at least) that it's a 2D array, yet I'm trying to splice like a 1D array of strings.

I've tried a switch, too, without success.

Thanks in advance for any assistance!

Comment: I really don't get your answer so I'm commenting: instead of using setValue in the for, assign the string value to the variable in the array that was just tested, as in `TESTalphaData[0][i] = 'FAB',`.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response, @Kriggs. I'll try it.

Comment: Tried it, @Kriggs. Script runs, but the whole loop seems to be skipped over. Also tried `TESTalphaData[0][i].push("FAB");` but that doesn't work--I think b/c push wants an integer.

Comment: Btw, the Google apps script editor only gives a dozen or so possibilities for var TESTalphaData inside the loop. Splice is one of them, which is why I tried that at one point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't just copy and use it, it's commented so you know what to do next time:

```
var TESTalpha = spreadsheet.getRange("E4:I4"),
    TESTalphaData = TESTalpha.getValues();

var col = TESTalphaData[0].length; // use a meaningful name for a variable
while( --col >= 0 ) {
// Make the tests and assign the variable the array you pulled from the sheet with getValues(), it's exactly the same you need to input with setValues()
if (TESTalphaData[0][col ] == "f") {
   TESTalphaData[0][col] = 'FAB';
} else if (TESTalphaData[0][col] == "p") {
   TESTalphaData[0][col] = "PAINT";
} else if (TESTalphaData[0][col] == "c") {
   TESTalphaData[0][col] = "FINISH";
}
// Setting the values should be after the loop is complete, so I removed it from inside the for (now a while), to the end of the code
}
// No need to get the Ranges again, you already save it up there
// No need to clear the range, it will all be re-written again
TESTalpha.setValues(TESTalphaData);
```

Comment: Thanks for the script, @Kriggs.  I haven't tried it, but I am about to. And don't worry, I've been at this a couple weeks because I want to learn something about JavaScript. Plus, I've got more to do on this script to make it useable on a weekly basis, so I need to understand and not just copy/paste anyway.

Comment: That does it! Thanks much, @Kriggs. Now on to adding borders to (only) populated cells...

Comment: Next I tried E4:I5. Row 4 is modified, but 5 is unchanged. I think that's b/c your script is calling only TESTalphaData[0] as I requested, so it's not going to look for TESTalphaData[1], etc. So the brackets need to contain another variable? And that variable has to be generated by another loop?

Comment: Yes, the `[0]` is the line, only the first one, you to check for `[0]` and `[1]`, which will be `TESTalphaData.length`. It doesn't matter if it is enclosing or beeing enclosed by the other `while`, as long as the `if`s are inside it and you change `[0]` for the looped variable.

Comment: Struggling, @Kriggs. Don't I need to do multiple `for` or `while` loops to examine all dimensions of TESTalphaData `array`? See my (bad) rough draft above as an update to my original question. Thanks!

Comment: It appears from Mozilla (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/while) that my `while` loop may be giving me something like [0][0], [1][1], and so on. I may need to control that first integer by a `for` loop superstructure or similar to regulate it such that I get [0][0], [0][1], etc....then [1][0], [1][1], etc.

Comment: `while` loop in a `while` loop works! Micro victory.

Answer (score 0):

Partial answer (still need help on putting borders around only the cells that contain a value). This `while` loop inside of another `while` changes values of the multiple dimensional array consisting of rows and columns. Many thanks to @Kriggs.

```
var TESTalpha = printCHSheet.getRange(4, 5, 7, 7),
    TESTalphaData = TESTalpha.getValues(),
    rowOp = TESTalpha.getNumRows();

while ( --rowOp >= 0 ) {

 var col = TESTalphaData[rowOp].length;

   while( --col >= 0 ) {

      if (TESTalphaData[rowOp][col] == "f") {
          TESTalphaData[rowOp][col] = "FAB";
      } else if (TESTalphaData[rowOp][col] == "p") {
                 TESTalphaData[rowOp][col] = "PAINT";
      } else if (TESTalphaData[rowOp][col] == "c") {
                 TESTalphaData[rowOp][col] = "FINISH";
      }

   }

}

TESTalpha.setValues(TESTalphaData);
```

The thing is, TESTalphaData is an array, so I can't set borders with it. I can set borders with TESTalpha (b/c it's a range), but then I get borders around exactly 7 cells per row (as I defined the range).

How can I run another loop to do something like this (which doesn't work)? `if (rangeX != null) {rangeX.setBorder(true, true, true, true, true, true);` Again, a range won't check values, but I can't set borders for values, since they exist in arrays apart from cells.

Really appreciate any help!

Answer (score 0):

This does it! A `for` loop inside a `for` loop to set borders if it's false that the cell's blank--**In other words**, if it's populated.

```
for (var r = 4; r < 50; r++) {

  for (var c = 5; c < 21; c++) {

       var singleCell = printCHSheet.getRange(r, c, 1, 1);
       var singleCellBlank = singleCell.isBlank();

     if ( !singleCellBlank ) {
                  singleCell.setBorder(true, true, true, true, true, true)
     }
  }
}
```

I'm elated. Now all I've got to do is format some fonts, add other letters to the `else if` evaluations, etc., and I'm done!